# Why is splay tree in textbook different than mine?

Tags: data-structures, binary-search-tree, avl-tree, treenode, splay-tree

In *Data Structures and Algorithm Analysis in C++ (4th Edition)* by Mark Allen Weiss, on page 162 at figure 4.50, the book describes how splaying the left most child of tree with only left children would ultimately look like.

Where I am confused is how the book gets from step 2 to step 3. Here are the steps highlighted on page 162 at figure 4.50:

[image]

Whereas my thirds step looks like this:

```
               7                                                                                          
              /                                                  
             6                                                   
            /                                                    
           1                    
            \                                                  
             3                                                  
            / \
           2   4
                \
                 5
```

And my fourth and final step like this:

```
    1
     \
      4
     / \
    3   6
   /   / \
  2    5  7
```

I am confused as to how the book is balancing the tree. For me, when 1 surpassed 4 the bottom of the tree looked like this:

```
  ...
 /
1
 \
  2
   \
    3
     \
      4
```

My logic was that the root where the balance would occur would be 2. Then you would do a left rotation and the bottom of the tree would look like this:

```
  ...
 /
1
 \
  3
 / \
2   4
```

Am I doing something wrong or am I just doing it in a different but equally valid to the book way? I am also confused because the book's final tree is imbalanced from the root of 6 whereas my root of 4 doesn't have an imbalance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mostly the "Zig-zig" case till upwards, so each time you do a right rotation on the node's grandparent followed by a right rotation on the parent.

Take example:

```
           5                                                                                          
          /                                                  
         4                                                   
        /                                                    
       3                    
      /                                                  
     2
    /
   1
```

If you want to splay 1, you rotate right around 3 then 2, resulting in:

```
        5                                                                                          
       /                                                  
      4                                                   
     /                                                    
    1
     \
      2
       \
        3
```

Since it is Zig-Zig case again, we rotate around 5 then 4, resulting:

```
   1
    \
     4
    / \
   2   5
    \
     3
```

So you keep doing this until you have 1 as root. There are 3 cases, Zig-Zig, Zig and Zig-Zag. [Here is a tool](https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/SplayTree.html) that visualizes the whole concept it will be helpful I believe.

Comment: Ah. For three nodes going in one direction you reverse their direction with 1 as the root.

Comment: Its actually right rotation at 3 making it a tree with root 2 and 1 to its left and 3 to its right. Then you rotate right around 2, making 1 the root and the result as above.